# How to filter query in SQL conditionally?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a query that shows me the earnings for each shop_id and country as below.

```
select shop_id,
       country,
       start_date,
       sum(earnings) as earnings
       
from x
where country IN ('DE', 'IT', 'ES')     
group by 1,2,3
```

However, I want to have only three shops in the country DE and all shops in the rest of the countries.

```
shop_id IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your criteria could use some nesting, like this:

```
select shop_id,
       country,
       start_date,
       sum(earnings) as earnings
       
from x
where country IN ('IT', 'ES') 
OR (country = 'DE' AND sop_id IN ('1','2','3'))
group by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause that checks for DE in the `country` column and returns only the three `shop_id`'s specified, otherwise return the `shop_id`.

```
WHERE
CASE 
    WHEN country = 'DE' AND shop_id IN ('1', '2', '3') THEN 1
    WHEN country IN ('IT', 'ES') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END = 1
```